# Gradle sync failed before upgrade and even after latest gradle upgrade

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

> Blockquote

error which im facing:  Im using latest android studio version 4.0.0 , i am unable to sync the gradle so i upgraded latest gradle version 6.5.1 and placed in path [c/program files/android/gradle/gradle 6.5.1/] .... iam getting sync failed error even after updation ..can anybody help me out from this error

> .[image: this issue]

[image: project structure]

[image: gradle path]

Comment: Solved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete  **`/project_directory/.gradle folder`**

Then upgrade

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

**`FYI`** - Make sure, You stop **`FireWall`** or **`Anti- Virus`**

Finally **`clean-Rebuild-Run`**